# Is it possible to have an user-interface and macros on sharepoint?

Tags: 2013, excel, database, vba

**Context**

I'm making a project on a company that must have an user interface and a database or work directly over an excel. Also I need this on SharePoint.

**Info**

The problem is that in the company, users can't install nothing. That's why i want it in SharePoint, for example.

We use excels because periodically we receive an .csv with updates, we use that to work over another excel.

I read that the security of many sites dont't allow this. [LINK](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12149/how-to-upload-and-open-exe-files-in-sharepoint-2010?newreg=a94ab6e4413945d4b6d27c97ac0c7a59). That's a problem beacuse here there is a lot of security so probably they won´t let me execute anything on SharePoint.

However, [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12149/how-to-upload-and-open-exe-files-in-sharepoint-2010?newreg=a94ab6e4413945d4b6d27c97ac0c7a59) says that I can run .exe if I am on IE with some JavaScript.

**Question**

So the question is if can I make for example a Visual or Java mini-interface that allows the user to access a excel and modify fields with some macros or directly with the program?

I am open-mind to use other method that permit working in a intranet on an user interface over a database.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to understand problem better, why does User Interface and macro need to be in Excel. Also, what does it mean by "need this on SharePoint". Are you planning to host it on SharePoint so that other can download it from there or something else?

Comment: The problem is that in the company, users can't install nothing. That's why i want it in SharePoint, for example. They're excels because periodically we receive an .csvwith updates, we use that to work over other excel. EDITED

Answer (score 0):

"They're excels because periodically we receive an .csvwith updates, we use that to work over other excel. "

You could use the excel services module in SharePoint.  This would allow you to display a **master Excel file** on SharePoint that you would keep updated with your new csv information. Users could then copy the cell information by doing a ctl+c to paste information into their spreadsheets.